# How to pass Request Header from Main view to Partial View in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2 View which is embedded in main inside  div as follows

1. @mainboard.applicationtraffic.render()

   above view has a parameter defined as @(implicit request: RequestHeader) on the top
   applicationtraffic. as I wanted to use websocket I defined that parameter

   Question: When I try to render  through 1. it ask for RequestHeader as a parameter 
   Could anyone please give me some sample code How to pass Request header to partial view
   render method

   Thank you in advance

```html
   
applicationtraffic.scala.html

@(implicit request: RequestHeader)

<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = new WebSocket("@routes.Application.applicationTrafficWS().webSocketURL()")
socket.onopen = function(event)
{
socket.send('I am the client and I\'m listening!');
socket.onmessage = function(event)
{
var datapoint = jQuery.parseJSON( event.data );
$("#data" ).html(datapoint);
};
socket.onclose = function(event)
{
console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event);
};
};
</script>
<div id="data">
  
</div>

Index.scala.html

    <div class="span4">
         <div class="widget" >
            <div class="widget-head">
                <h4 class="heading glyphicons cardio"><i></i>Application Traffic</h4>
                  </div>
                     <div class="widget-body">
                       @mainboard.applicationtraffic.render(Context.current.get()._requestHeader())
                  </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I believe you need to pass the request to main template from `Play!` controller using static method `request()` from `Controller` class and pass it over to sub-template.

Comment: Could you kindly send me little code snippet hos to do it in controller using scala

Comment: Hi Ryan I posted code i want to render @mainboard.applicationtraffic.render(RequestHeader) Could you kindly give me code sample of doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example how to get what you want with passing the `request` as an implicit parameter. First of all, you need to declare the implicit parameter in your `index.html`:

**index.scala.html**

```
@()(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)
<div class="span4">
  <div class="widget" >
    <div class="widget-head">
      <h4 class="heading glyphicons cardio"><i></i>Application Traffic</h4>
    /div>
    <div class="widget-body">
      @applicationtraffic()
    /div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the empty parameter list as well as how the partial view is invoked (I've removed the mainboard prefix in this example since you named your partial view `applicationtraffic.scala.html`). Because you want to pass the request as an implicit and we have no explicit parameters, you need to add empty parentheses again:

**applicationtraffic.scala.html**

```
@()(implicit request: RequestHeader)

<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div>...</div>
```

And finally, your controller method should declare the `request` parameter as `implicit`:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index())
}
```